# Connection failed when updating to Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android-studio

When trying to update Android Studio to version 2.3, I get a "Connection failed. Connection timed out" message on a perfectly good internet connection. Check the screenshot below please: [image: Screenshot of error]

I'm trying to update using **Help -> Check for updates** and also **Settings -> Appearance and Behavior -> System Settings -> Updates -> Check Now**

Also, **Settings -> Appearance and Behavior -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy** is set to **No-Proxy**.

Am I missing something here?
Thanks guys!